# How to Count upto a cell in Googlesheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a Google Sheet that looks like this:
[image]

What formula can I use in column B to count the number of P's on the row up to the first found 'G'?
If there is no G I just want the total number of P's

So **B6** should total **6** and **B8** should total **9**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you've meant till the first G found? Because if you want to count from first G answer in B8 should be 4.

Comment: I wanted to count from C8:P8 (P8 is where the first G is)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

B3:

```
=FIND("G",TEXTJOIN(,1,C3:3)&"G")-1
```

- TEXTJOIN all Ps and Gs excluding blanks
- FIND the first G position in the resulting string

Comment: Brilliant answer! So simple!

Answer (score 1):

Ugly but works. Put in B3 and drag down for your rows. This is for counting after G

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("G",OFFSET($C3,0,0,1,MATCH("zzz",3:3)-2),0)),COUNTIF(OFFSET($C3,0,0,1,MATCH("zzz",3:3)-2),"P"),COUNTIF(OFFSET(C3,,MATCH("G",OFFSET($C3,0,0,1,MATCH("zzz",3:3)-2),0),1,MATCH("zzz",3:3)-MATCH("G",OFFSET($C3,0,0,1,MATCH("zzz",3:3)-2),0)-2),"P"))
```

If counting before G

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISERROR(MATCH("G",OFFSET($C3,0,0,1,MATCH("zzz",3:3)-2),0)),COUNTIF(OFFSET($C3,0,0,1,MATCH("zzz",3:3)-2),"P"),COUNTIF(OFFSET(C3,,,1,MATCH("G",OFFSET($C3,0,0,1,MATCH("zzz",3:3)-2),0)),"P")),0)
```

Comment: Did you try this at all? Or at least some feedback? And didn't you say count all the "P"s from/after finding the first G?

Comment: I think it was an English issue in the question - they meant 'to' the first G rather than 'from' the first G :-) I will take it upon myself to edit it.

Comment: @I'-'I Lol. Ok. I've written both now. Though your answer is so short as to make mine feel like the elephant in the room :-)